# urllib request.urlopen(url).read() with SQLAlchemy is storing a hex string instead of HTML

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, urllib

I'm trying to store some HTML in postgres using **urllib** and **SQLAlchemy** but it seems like something is getting garbled in the process when the html is being inserted\retrieved

using: **SQLAlchemy 1.2, Python 3.6, postgres 10, urllib**

```
class ParksTxState(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parks_tx_state'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    park_name = Column(Text)
    url = Column(Text)
    html = Column(Text)


engine = create_engine("postgresql://<user>:<pass>@localhost/<db>", echo=False)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

url = 'https://tpwd.texas.gov/state-parks/abilene'
html = request.urlopen(url).read()

print(html)
# b'<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">\n<head>\n...
# so far so good...

newpark = ParksTxState()
newpark.html = html

print(newpark.html)
# b'<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">\n<head>\n...
# so we're still good here before committing....

session.add(newpark)
session.commit()

print(newpark.html)
# \x3c21444f43545950452068746d6c3e0a3...
# and here is where the garbage comes in.
```

For some reason the HTML is being stored as a long string of characters..
`\x3c21444f43545950452068746d6c3e0a3c68746d6c20786d6c6e733d22687474703a2f2f7777772e7...`

I've even set `echo=True` and saw that the insert statement was correct.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it looks like `request.urlopen(url).read()` is returning a `bytes` object (see [Methods of File Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects).)  This needs to be converted to a string with `.decode('utf-8')`

```
html = request.urlopen(url).read()
html_string = html.decode('utf-8')
```

also see [Convert bytes to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-string)